# Expanding contact box

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make an expanding contact box but am having trouble with the javascript.. Current this is my code:

```
        function openTab() {

            var tab = document.getElementById('contact_body');

            if(tab.style.display = 'none') {
                tab.style.display = 'block';
            } else if(tab.style.display = 'block') {
                tab.style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
```

I am making it so that when you click the tab below it opens out (This part works) and then when you click it again, it closes (this does not work).

CLOSED:

[image]

OPEN:

[image]

The tab can be opened, but can't close, Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It should be two 'equals to' sign,

```
if(tab.style.display == 'none')
```